# Eloquent relations - attach (but don't save) Relation of a Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following relations set up:

```
class Carpeta extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey='id_carpeta'; 
    protected  $table='tdoc_carpetas';

    public  function detallesMantenimiento()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('DetalleMantenimiento','id_carpeta');
    }
}

class DetalleMantenimiento extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey='id_detalle_mantenimiento'; 
    protected  $table='tdoc_detalle_mantenimiento';

    public function detallesPiezasMantenimiento() 
    { 
        return $this->hasMany('DetallePiezasMantenimiento','id_detalle_mantenimiento'); 
    }            
}

class DetallePiezasMantenimiento extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey='id_detalle_piezas_mantenimiento'; 
    protected  $table='tdoc_detalle_piezas';

    public function detalleMantenimiento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('DetalleMantenimiento','id_detalle_mantenimiento'); 
    }
}
```

My question is how attach(without save)  DetallePiezasMantenimiento's item, I attempt as following :

```
$detallePieza = new DetallePiezasMantenimiento();
$carpeta->detallesMantenimiento->detallesPiezasMantenimiento->add($detallePieza);
```

but 
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$detallesPiezasMantenimiento` return.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that `detallesMantenimiento` is a collection. Do you want to add it to `detallesPiezasMantenimiento` of every `detalleMantenimiento` in the collection?

Comment: I need such as $detalleMantenimiento = new DetalleMantenimiento();
           $carpeta->detallesMantenimiento->add($detalleMantenimiento);

Comment: Yes I got that... let me rephrase my question with `A`, `B` and `C` (sorry your variable names are hard for me to read) `A` has many `B`s > no problem to add one. `A` has many `B`s which each have many `C`s > do you want to add a `C` to every `B` or just to one specific?

Comment: I want to add many C to every B, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `detallesMantenimiento` is a collection you need to loop over it to add `$detallePieza` to the relationship result

```
$detallePieza = new DetallePiezasMantenimiento();
foreach($carpeta->detallesMantenimiento as $detalleMantenimiento){
    $detalleMantenimiento->detallesPiezasMantenimiento->add($detallePieza);
}
```